# Shopware pwa ERROR [MIDDLEWARE][DOMAINS] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Tags: shopware, shopware6, vue-storefront, shopware6-api

shopware-pwa.config.js

```
 module.exports = {
  shopwareEndpoint: "https://s19157.creolineserver.com",
  shopwareAccessToken: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  pwaHost: "https://s19157.creolineserver.com",
  shopwareDomainsAllowList: [
    "https://s19157.creoline.cloud/cs",
    "https://s19157.creoline.cloud/sk",
    "https://s19157.creoline.cloud"
  ]
};
```

After run command `yarn generate`

I get lots of errors

```
 ERROR  [MIDDLEWARE][DOMAINS] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')                                                                                                                                                                   01:21:17

  at extractApiErrorMessage (server.js:392:50)
  at errorInterceptor (server.js:407:54)
  at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
  at async updateContext (server.js:849:16)
  at async setCurrentCurrency (server.js:886:16)
  at async setCurrency (server.js:2256:5)
  at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

Please guide what am I doing wrong?